# Change format date when retrieve it from sql

Tags: php, sql, laravel, apache

When I Retrieve date from SQL database in my laptop only it back to me like (May 17 2016 12:00:00:AM) but any server or another laptop back like (2016-05-17), it appears when I call date column from database and I think this issue not from code I think in PHP or apache2 in my laptop.

This is my code:

```php
$user_data = User::with('employee')
    ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->get()
    ->first()
    ->toArray();

dd($user_data['employee']['hire_date']);
```

[image]

Comment: you can convert this to your desired format via code

Comment: edit your question, adding your code, i.e the sql statement which fetches the date column

Comment: Please can you add the code that is returning the date.

Comment: You are able to format date at either MySQL level or PHP level. First, in general, will be faster. Which way would you like to go?

Comment: It would be far more efficient for you to do just `->first()` instead of `->get()->first()`

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is occuring is likely to be because on your laptop you have a DATETIME field in the database and on the server you have a DATE field. These field types are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [mutators in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator), and also using the **Carbon** package.

It should be implemented like this:

**Employee.php**

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Employee extends Model {

public function setHireDateAttribute($value)
{
    $carbonDate = Carbon::create($value)
    $this->attributes['hire_date']->toDateString();
}

}
```

Comment: This should be in the `Employee` model rather than the `User` model.

Comment: @RossWilson That's right, I edited my answer.